# Join file in APK to store them in SD card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

For some reason i need to join some defaut file with my apk but i need to write to sd card because my app try to read the sd card i need to store the first time my default file in sd card

How to do this i can't paste my data in my root folder android refuse it if i paste it on a drawable folder it seems ok for compiling but i still duno how to get content and write on my sd card

I have see many tuto tu get a drawable from sd card but i wan't the opposite i will write a file on sd card from a default file i have join to apk

Any idea? i don't have code because i don't have any tips to do that

Comment: Can you try to write in complete sentences?  I can't understand what the problem is.

Comment: This should not be closed - to those familiar with android it's a real question, and as the accepted answer indicates, an answerable one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zip your file(s) and put the zip file (name it `my_raw_files.zip`) into folder `res/raw` in Eclipse and it will be packaged together with your app. Then you can copy it at first start of your app to the external storage ("sdcard"):

```
private static final File USER_DIR = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator
        + "myfolder");
...
boolean dirCreated = USER_DIR.mkdirs();
if (dirCreated)
{
  FilesUtil.unzipFiles(this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.my_raw_files),
                    USER_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
}
...
static public void unzipFiles(InputStream zipIS, String outputPath)
{
    try
    {
        // unzip files into existing folder structure
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(zipIS);
        try
        {
            ZipEntry ze;
            while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null)
            {
                if (!ze.isDirectory())
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "unzip " + ze.getName());

                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int count;
                    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(outputPath + File.separator + ze.getName());
                    while ((count = zin.read(buffer)) != -1)
                    {
                        baos.write(buffer, 0, count);
                        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
                        fout.write(bytes);
                        baos.reset();
                    }
                    fout.close();
                }
            }
        } finally
        {
            zin.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "unzip", e);
    }

}
```